# MS Access Query - How to define a date range based only on the input date

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access Query - How to define a date range based only on the input date

Hello, I have a table that showcases the steps in an approval process.

```
ID   |OriginalID|   OraclePricelistName |Change           |ItemNumber| Modified | Approval|PCTask | OESTask
2363 |  5,529   |   price_list1         | No              | Item1    |2020-06-09| Approved|No task|No task
2352 |  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-06-09| Approved|Ready  |Ready
2332 |  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-06-09| Approved|Ready  |Pending
2325 |  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-06-08| Approved|Pending|Pending
2312 |  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-06-08| Pending |Pending|Pending
14422|  5,529   |   price_list1         |No               | Item1    |2020-01-15| Approved|No task|No task
14419|  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-01-15| Approved|Ready  |No task
14184|  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-01-14| Approved|Pending|Pending
14121|  5,529   |   price_list1         |Workflow running | Item1    |2020-01-13| Pending |Pending|Pending
11434|  5,529   |   price_list1         |No               | Item1    |2019-12-27| Approved|No task|No task
```

I was tasked with creating a query that shows when each step of the workflow was completed and to filter the results based on an input date. I’ve managed to create the part of the query that determines the date of completion for each step. However, I am having difficulties specifying the range only by the input date. I know that each new range starts  when the column “Change” changes its status from “No” to “Workflow running” and ends when it changes back “No”. I tried using alias columns and filtering by them without success.

```
PARAMETERS [CheckDate] DateTime;
SELECT DISTINCT archive_prices.ID, archive_prices.OriginalID, archive_prices.OraclePricelistName, archive_prices.Change, archive_prices.ItemNumber, archive_prices.CustomerItemNumber, archive_prices.Currency, archive_prices.Modified, archive_prices.Created, archive_prices.Approval, archive_prices.CSSTask, archive_prices.PCTask, archive_prices.OESTask, archive_prices.CSTask, archive_prices.MultiYear,

IIF([Change]='Workflow running' AND [Approval]='Pending' AND [PCTask]='Pending' AND [OESTask]='Pending',[Modified],'Blank') AS UpdateDate,
 IIF([Approval]='Approved' AND [PCTask]='Pending' AND [OESTask]='Pending',[Modified],'Blank') AS ApprovalDate,
  IIF([PCTask]='Ready' AND [OESTask]='Pending',[Modified],'Blank' ) AS OracleUpdate,
    IIF([OESTask]='Ready',[Modified],'Blank') AS BacklogUpdate, 


IIF([Change]='No',[Modified],"Blank") AS CompletedTask,
 IIF([Change]='Workflow running',[Modified],"Blank") AS WorkflowTask,
  IIF([CheckDate]>=Nz([CompletedTask]),1,IIF([CheckDate]>=Nz([WorkflowTask]),1,0)) AS Range


FROM archive_prices
WHERE (((archive_prices.OraclePricelistName)=[PriceList]) AND ((archive_prices.ItemNumber)=[PartNumber]))
ORDER BY archive_prices.Modified;
```

If I enter the date 06/10/2020 in the CheckDate parameter the query should give out the following result:

```
ID  OriginalID  OraclePricelistName Change  ItemNumber  Modified    Approval    PCTask  OESTask UpdateDate  ApprovalDate    OracleUpdate    BacklogUpdate
2352    5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-06-09  Approved    Ready   Ready       Null        Null         Null             2020-06-09
2332    5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-06-09  Approved    Ready   Pending     Null        Null         2020-06-09       Null
2325    5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-06-08  Approved    Pending Pending     Null        2020-06-08   Null             Null
2312    5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-06-08  Pending Pending Pending     2020-06-08  Null         Null             Null
```

If I enter the date 01/10/2020 then the query should show:

```
ID  OriginalID  OraclePricelistName Change  ItemNumber  Modified    Approval    PCTask  OESTask UpdateDate  ApprovalDate    OracleUpdate    BacklogUpdate
14419   5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-01-15  Approved    Ready   No task     Null      Null            2020-01-15        Null
14184   5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-01-14  Approved    Pending Pending     Null      2020-01-14      Null              Null
14121   5,529   price_list1 Workflow running    Item1   2020-01-13  Pending Pending Pending       2020-01-13  Null            Null              Null
```

I'm new to access so my approach is most likely wrong in this case and I hope that you can help me find the correct one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show (and not simply tell) your desired results using sample data.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I gave two examples of what should be the result of the query. Hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

As you're new in access I suggest you to go by parts, as follow:

Supposing ID is autonumber and incremental, you can create a first query called "Q1" like

```
Select OraclePricelistName, max(ID) from archive_prices GROUP BY OraclePricelistName HAVING change = "Workflow running"
```

The above will give you the last ID by OraclePricelistName where a change started.

Then you do a second query ("Q2") as:

```
Select OraclePricelistName, max(ID) from archive_prices GROUP BY OraclePricelistName HAVING change = "no"
```

The above will give you the last ID by OraclePricelistName where a change finished.

Then you do

```
Select Q1.*, Q2.* from Q1 LEFT JOIN Q2 ON Q1.OraclePricelistName = Q2.OraclePricelistName
```

The above will show the data you need. Please note when Q2.id is lower than Q1.id means a change has started but hasn't been closed yet.

Comment: Hi @Fabricio Fonseca, thanks for taking the time to answer! I think this is the approach I need to use, however I'm not getting to the result that's intended. By going with max ID I will always get the latest inputs. However the end user may want to check past periods, so i need to tie the CheckDate parameter somehow to the code. I will try and modify your suggestion and see if I can get to the end result.